# SQL query with null values

Tags: mysql, database

I have been stuck to this in almost a day. I'm not quite knowledgeable with database since I'm new at it.

I have a table like this

### questions table

```
question_strand | question_number | question_difficulty
     part 1     |        1        |        easy
       ..       |       ...       |         ...
     part 1     |        20       |        medium
       ..       |       ...       |         ...
     part 10    |        20       |        difficult
```

composite key: **question_strand** and **question_number**

**the question table consist of 10 parts with 20 items each and difficulty with each number.** Also this table has question_items and other columns which I did not include in the example because its not related to the question

### question answer table

```
question_strand | question_number | question_answer | student_name
     part 1     |         1       |       true      |    gerald
      ...       |        ...      |        ...      |      ...
     part 1     |        20       |       wrong     |    gerald
```

composite key **question_strand**, **student_name** and **question_number**

**question answer table is also consist of question_strand and question_number but has question_answer and student_name**

I want to only select the answer of a specific student.

This is the result I want to get

```
question_strand | question_number | question_answer | student_name
     part 1     |         1       |       true      |    gerald
      ...       |        ...      |        ...      |      ...
     part 1     |        20       |       wrong     |    gerald
     part 2     |         1       |       null      |     null
      ...       |        ...      |        ...      |     ...
     part 10    |        20       |       null      |     null
```

I want to get all questions but also include null values if it doesn't have any value correspond to the second table

I'm using mySQL. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use left join

```
SELECT
  q.question_strand,
  q.question_number,
  a.question_answer,
  q.student_name
FROM
    questions_table q LEFT JOIN answer_table a
      ON q.question_strand = a.question_strand AND
         q.question_number = a.question_number
```

If you want records for specific student

```
SELECT
  q.question_strand,
  q.question_number,
  a.question_answer,
  q.student_name
FROM
    questions_table q LEFT JOIN answer_table a
      ON q.question_strand = a.question_strand AND
         q.question_number = a.question_number AND
         q.student_name    = 'gerald'
```

Comment: @newbie have you try my answer.

Comment: Yes. This works fine except that it selects all the names. Can I have only one specific name?

Answer (score 0):

You haven't specified your actual queries, so it's difficult for me to help you.

```
SELECT question_strand, question_number, question_answer, student_name
FROM question_answers
WHERE student_name = "gerald" OR student_name IS NULL
```

This query will pull in all data from `question_answers` where the student is called Gerald, or they have no name.
This should pull the data you're wanting from what I understand.

Comment: I don't see the second table here.

Comment: I didn't see any need. This does what you want from what I can see in your schema.

Comment: I want to get all question_strand not only the answered once.